# Batch fails with SQL error "String data, right truncated..." for node field

Tags: nodes

Batch fails with SQL error "String data, right truncated..." for node field_collection field. But when saving node with the same field value there is no errors and Drupal log has no errors corresponding that problem.

Here is batch callback

```
function lt_generator_generate_text($report_nid, $context) {
  $node = node_load($report_nid);
  $report = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  if ($report->type->value() == 'report') {
    if (LT_GENERATOR_DEBUG) watchdog('lt_generator_node_started', $report_nid);
    foreach ($report->field_report as $report_info) {
      if ($report_info->field_task_title->value()) {
        $report_info->field_task_title->set(_generate_random_text($report_info->field_task_title->value()));
      }
      if ($report_info->field_issue_title->value()) {
        $report_info->field_issue_title->set(_generate_random_text($report_info->field_issue_title->value()));
      }
      $report_info->save();
    }
    $context['results'][] = $node->title;
    $context['message'] = t('Text generated for @node_title', array('@node_title' => $node->title));
    if (LT_GENERATOR_DEBUG) watchdog('lt_generator_node_finished', $report_nid);
  }  
}
```

This callback is simply generates random text with the same length as its value and save field_collection ($report_info->save();)

field_task_title - varchar(255), is russian or english text or even mixed.

I was looking at the length of these strings and found out it is 259 length both (one that was as field value and another one generated string). So while processing batch it fails to save field_task_title with 259 length string, but saving node is succeeded with the same string, that makes me confused. Any ideas why this happens for nodes? Also have u any ideas how to make batch don't fail everytime?

Comment: Varchar fields can only hold max 255 chars. Try to truncate your random text to 255 chars, that should do the trick